# separating image tag from image resizing

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I currently have a function in PHP called img(), that takes at least two arguments, as such:

```
print img("foo.jpg", 100);
```

That would return something like this:

```
<img src='/cache/foo_XXXXX.jpg' width='100' height='76' />
```

So, the function takes the arguments, resize the original file and save it as a cached file on the server and return the image tag. Obviously, if the cached version already exists, it just returns it and saves the processing for the next time.

Now, this works perfectly in 99 cases out of 100, but for some sites there are pages which are quite image-heavy, and since the cached versions of the image is expired after X number of days, the img() functions needs to recreate 50+ high resolution images to small thumbnails, and loading such a page takes several seconds and that's not acceptable.

So my idea is to separate this. So doing this:

```
print img("foo.jpg", 100);
```

would return this:

```
<img src='img.php?ARGUMENTS' width='?' height='?' />
```

Which means that the img() function doesn't actually handle the file at all, but rather output HTML that tells the browser to get the image from a PHP script rather than a static image file on the server.

Now, the "ARGUMENT" part would of course contain all the information that img.php needs to deal with the file in the same way that img() has dealt with it - perhaps a serialized string version of all the arguments to the function?

But the problem is the width/height values of the image tag! Since processing is moved outside the scope of the current script, it has no idea how large the resulting image would be, right? I obviously can't wait for img.php to complete and return it. I am using imagemagick for the processing (so the second argument can be 100, "50%", "<40" and whatnot) and perhaps there is a way to "dryrun" it with imagemagick - i.e. having imagemagick return the resulting size of a specific file using a specific command?

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have the list of all images somewhere in database, right? You can add the fields for width and height and calculate scaled width and height while generating HTML. You could also add thumbnails width and height into database as well.

Comment: No, the images are just files on the hard drive of the server. At least as far as the img() tag is concerned. In some cases, the reference to the file is kept in a database, but we're talking about tons of different databases for different purposes, all using img() for display